# Visually comparing variances

Tags: data-analysis, visualization, oceanography

I have a dataset containing 8 categories, I now want to visually compare the variance between the categories. The most common approach would be to use box plots or violin plots but I would like to know if there are other "more exciting" ways of doing that?

Comment: "More exciting" in what way?

Comment: I am just looking for suggestions. I want to learn about different plot option.